# Guarding specific resources against enumeration attacks

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm using Apache 2.2 as a proxy for my app server.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/A [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/B
RewriteRule (.+) http://appserver$1 [P]
```

In normal use, the number of legitimate requests for /A is several orders of magnitude higher than for /B

/B is vulnerable to a dictionary attack, and I would like to mitigate the risk by putting tight limits on the number of /B requests that get serviced within some time window.

How can I restrict the requests to /B without interfering with requests to /A?

Comment: There are clues that I'm looking for mod_security, or mod_evasive, or mod_bandwidth, but I haven't found an example that clearly shows me which is the best fit for my circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that a reasonable answer is

- grab and install [mod_security](http://www.modsecurity.org/download/)
- grab and install the [OWASP ModSecurity Core Rule Set](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_ModSecurity_Core_Rule_Set_Project#tab=Home)
- copy modsecurity_crs_10_config.conf.example to modsecurity_crs_10_config.conf
- Enable Brute Force Protection in that file

```
    SecAction "phase:1,id:'981214',t:none,nolog,pass, \
    setvar:'tx.brute_force_protected_urls=/B', \
    setvar:'tx.brute_force_burst_time_slice=60', \
    setvar:'tx.brute_force_counter_threshold=10', \
    setvar:'tx.brute_force_block_timeout=300'"
```

- update httpd.conf

```
<IfModule security2_module>
    Include conf/modsecurity_crs/*.conf
    Include conf/modsecurity_crs/experimental_rules/modsecurity_crs_11_brute_force.conf
</IfModule>
```

- And finally, turn it on

```
    SecRuleEngine On
```

What this gets you is is a check during [the logging phase](http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/modsecurity-apache/2.5.0/html-multipage/processing-phases.html); if there has been two or more bursts, then the offending IP address will be sent to the corner for a timeout, and ALL subsequent requests from that IP will be forbidden until the timeout expires.

When testing, keep in mind that (a) more than brute_force_counter_threshold requests make up a burst, 2 bursts lead to a block, and that block starts after the request that trips the second burst.  (If brute_force_counter_threshold = 3, you'll see 8 unblocked attempts before the blocks start).

brute_force_protected_urls allows you to specify multiple vulnerable points

```
'tx.brute_force_protected_urls=/B /C'
```

but if you want multiple policies, you'll want a second copy of modsecurity_crs_11_brute_Force.conf with search and replaced variable names.